# How to Inject Variable into Child Directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

For the following angularjs directives:

```
app = angular.module('ngApp');

app.value('objects', [
  {id: 1, name: 'Jane Doe', active: true},
  {id: 2, name: 'Test Biz', active: false},
  {id: 3, name: 'Another Business', active: false}
]);

app.directive('myDirective', function (objects) {
     return {
       template: '<ul></ul>',
       replace: true,
       compile: function(element, attrs) {
          for(var i=0;i<objects.length;i++) {
            element.append('<div other-directive object={{object}}></div>');
         }
       }
    };
})
.directive('otherDirecctive', function() {
   return {
     template: '<li>{{object.name}}',
     replace: true,
     scope: { object: '=' }
 });
```

And this bit of html:

```
<div my-directive></div>
```

How do I pass each object into the sub-directive? Is there a better overall way to structure this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using just one directive and harness `ng-repeat` in the template:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function (objects) {
     return {
       link: function(scope,element,attrs){
           scope.objects = objects;    
       },
       template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="o in objects">{{o.name}}</li></ul>'
    };
});
```

But if you still want to use the second directive, you can use as is, just change the template of the first to:

```
'<ul><li ng-repeat="o in objects" other-directive object="o"></li></ul>'
```

**Demo:** [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/97wPU/)

Comment: It was the link function that I was missing. Thanks so much!